# Parsing version out of a pom.xml in bash

Tags: regex, xml, bash, grep

Here is a snippet from my shell script -

```
regex="<version>([0-9]*)\.([0-9]*)\.([0-9]*)([^<]*)<\/version>.*"

#some unrelated lines of code

    echo $(grep -m 1 "<version>" $1)
    if [[ $(grep -m 1 "<version>" $1) =~ $regex ]]
    then
        main_version = "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        feature_version = "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        patch_version = "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
        tag = "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    else
        echo "$1: Version not Found" >&2
    fi
```

But it is showing me the following output -

```
<version>1.1.7-release</version> <!-- ABC version -->
abc/xyz/pom.xml: Version not Found
```

But according to my understanding, `regex` should match with the output of `grep`(i echoed it to terminal for better clarity). So can someone tell what am i doing wrong?

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.company.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.7-release</version> <!-- abc version -->
</project>
```

Comment: There are better tools (`xmllint` and `xmlstarlet`) for querying XML files than treating them as line-oriented files with `grep`.

Comment: There would seem to be a problem with your call to `grep`; `[[ "<version>1.1.7-release</version> <!-- ABC version -->" =~ $regex ]]` succeeds for me.

Comment: You'll need to remove the spaces from around the `=` in your assignments; `main_version=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`, etc.

Comment: @chepner thanks i will look into them...but i cant find `man` page for `xmlstarlet` so do i need to download it? And is there some site or page where they give example on their usage

Comment: @chepner i have added a sample `pom.xml` in the question, try using `pom.xml` in `grep` instead of `$1` ie `grep -m 1 "<version>" pom.xml` and see if it works because thats what is causing problem in my cae

Comment: and lastly thanks for the tip wow i just realised that all three were your comments......but this doesnt have much to do with the error though i would have been happy if this was the reason

Comment: Works for me. Does your script use DOS line endings, in which case `regex` would end with `\r`?

Comment: Why use bash for something like this? You wouldn't use bash to parse JSON or YAML, you'd install something like `jq` or `yq`, the latter also parses [XML documents](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) anyway

Comment: i just realised it was because of `export -f func_name` which i had used earlier to pass my function to `xargs` and yeah the above piece of code was part of that function of mine...never knew they were related

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem just for learning how to use shell script

Comment: @monster, ...part of how to write shell scripts is knowing when to reach for external tools. Trying to work with structured data formats with tools that don't understand that structure is a quick way to interop problems (and unhappy clients or integration partners) when applied in the real world: It's **really** easy to make a semantically-equivalent document that any parser will understand as identical to the original, but that a string-manipulation-based "parser" won't recognize. And it's easy to have that happen by accident.

Comment: ...for an example of the "accident" case, consider what happens if someone decides to put your entire block of data about the current project on a single line; suddenly, `grep` can't pick out an individual item anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Using [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html):

```
regex='^([0-9]*)[.]([0-9]*)[.]([0-9]*)(.*)'
version=$(xmlstarlet sel -N mvn='http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0' \
                         -t -m '/mvn:project/mvn:version' -v . -n <pom.xml)

if [[ $version =~ $regex ]]; then
    main_version="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    feature_version="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    patch_version="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
    tag="${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    declare -p main_version feature_version patch_version tag
else
    echo "Could not extract or parse version tag" >&2
fi
```

...properly emits as output, given your `pom.xml`:

```
declare -- main_version="1"
declare -- feature_version="1"
declare -- patch_version="7"
declare -- tag="-release"
```